# Can I bring spices, nuts, or dates to New Zealand if they're not labeled commercially?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, new-zealand

I read the customs agency's website, but I did not understand the conditions. I have several ground spices; however, they are not labeled commercially. Can I bring them with me when I go to New Zealand?

How about walnuts, pistachios, almonds, Indian almonds, and dates?

Comment: I am not sure but I think non of those are allowed.

Comment: @Willeke no I am sure some of them are allowed actually

Comment: I am sure some people have entered New Zealand with home produced spices but as far as I understand the rules (and this is confirmed by the answer that has since been given) it is not allowed. This is one of the countries which are very sharp on not allowing biological hazards in.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to bring your own spices to NZ instead of buying them there?

Comment: I bring them since they are expensive there! Also, you should ask customs why they put it in website if you ask me why i bring!! everybody has a reason!

Comment: Useful (hopefully) info only: I live in NZ and travel internationally moderately. The incoming inspections for biological products are stringent and violations of the rules meet with a fine of (I think) $200 in minor cases - not negotiable or waivable regardless of reason. There is a clearly marked "Discrad bad stuff here" bin - beyond that you are in trouble. They have "XRAY" machines that can identify biological products. I suggest that if a product may be borderline that you enquire of them in advance. || ...

Comment: ... I brought in a plastic "cows horn" - their machine spotted it and also identified that it was NOT made of animal byproducts :-).

Comment: Ok  the worst scenario is if you inform them about no problem just they put them in trash but there is no problem if I bring things that are dried and based on rules

Comment: When trying to figure out what you can bring it helps to consider **why** the biosecurity rules are in place. They want to stop insects, plant diseases, and to a lesser extent viable seeds. If it is in unopened commercial packaging it is unlikely to have live insects or eggs in it. If it is dried/ground/cooked it is unlikely to have plant diseases. Anything not clearly safe they will be cautious and not let you bring it in. Remember to always declare all food/animal products/plant products and you will be ok, worst case they will confiscate it.

Comment: Just to be clear - all those items are available retail in New Zealand, though the prices reflect they are not grown locally and likely cost more than you'd pay at home.

Comment: "likely cost more than you'd pay at home" but cheaper than NZ$200 per baggie.

Comment: @shoover NZ$200 *and* not even getting to keep the baggie!

Comment: It is bot 200 but 400. If you declare it is 0. see the rule and bring vased on that. Nz is expensive

Comment: Are you traveling to NZ for a short visit, or are you immigrating there and/or going to be there for months or longer?

Comment: Longer!........

Answer (score 25):

The New Zealand government's main site is [Check if you can bring or send an item to NZ](https://www.mpi.govt.nz/bring-send-to-nz/bringing-and-posting-items-to-nz/check-if-you-can-bring-or-send-an-item-to-nz/).

Following it to specific food items, it says about:

[Spices](https://www.mpi.govt.nz/bring-send-to-nz/bringing-and-posting-items-to-nz/check-if-you-can-bring-or-send-an-item-to-nz/food/honey-herbs-and-spices/#herbs):

> Allowed if: If it is dried and ground, commercially manufactured and packaged.

[Nuts](https://www.mpi.govt.nz/bring-send-to-nz/bringing-and-posting-items-to-nz/check-if-you-can-bring-or-send-an-item-to-nz/food/nuts-seeds-legumes-and-beans/#nuts):

> Allowed if: It is commercially manufactured and packaged, and is listed here.

So in both cases, it is a clear **no** for non-commercial produce.

---

Regarding [dates](https://www.mpi.govt.nz/bring-send-to-nz/bringing-and-posting-items-to-nz/check-if-you-can-bring-or-send-an-item-to-nz/food/fruit-vegetable-and-fungi-products/#fruit-veg), they say:

> Allowed if: It is fully dried, freeze-dried, dehydrated, juiced, pureed, pulped, cooked, roasted, stewed, minced, baked, parboiled, preserved, pickled, powdered, flaked, made into syrup, made into pills, made into capsules, or commercially frozen.

This seems to rule out fresh dates.

Comment: Thanks. Saffron is also same right? If it is commercial that is Ok? I have dried dates, is that Ok based on this rule? Date has nucleus inside it. So, in case it is dried that is not a problem right?

Comment: Also, I could not find any link for dried grape without core and commercial. Is it Ok?

Comment: As saffron is listed among the 'spices' I think you can assume that the spice rule applies: it has to be commercially ground, packaged and labelled to be allowed. As for the dates: the website states **fully dried**. If they still contain the pit, it seems likely they are not processed in other ways. As for dried grapes, they are called 'sultanas' or 'raisins' so are on that list too. Note that all these items are widely available in New Zealand, so there seems little point bringing them yourself.

Comment: I presume the "ground" rule is there to ensure there are no viable seeds left.  Since saffron threads are not seeds and cannot reproduce, grinding should not be necessary -- but I'd still confirm this if you're planning to import a kilo!

Comment: @lambshaanxy perhaps, but I would not put myself in the position of explaining to a customs officer why their rules are incorrect :)

Comment: Also the "commercially manufactured and packaged." - I've seen people have all sorts of things confiscated that are otherwise allowed but are not in the original packaging.

Comment: @ weather vane nothing written about pit inside date. https://www.mpi.govt.nz/bring-send-to-nz/bringing-and-posting-items-to-nz/check-if-you-can-bring-or-send-an-item-to-nz/food/fruit-vegetable-and-fungi-products/#fruit-veg

Comment: The site says that unground things may be OK; but if it's unground, then as well as being commercially manufactured and packaged, it must be unopened.

Comment: @Turkan the point about having a pit is that the dates won't be processed: therefore they must be fully dried.

Comment: @lambshaanxy yes, the spice rule states "If it is unground it must also be in its original unopened packaging."

Comment: "Note that all these items are widely available in New Zealand, so there seems little point bringing them yourself" - true of sultanas/raisins, but saffron is much more valuable and it would be an appropriate gift for a visitor to from (eg) Iran to bring to family.

Answer (score 7):

If you bring the spices and it is all clearly commercially prepared food of the types allowed they will ask to inspect it, and if it is good  they will allow it, if it is not good they will take it, but because you are being honest there will be no problem.

If you try to avoid the inspection there will be a fine and it will be confiscated.  New Zealand is a low corruption country, bribes will not work, if you try it will make matters worse.

> I bring them since they are expensive there! Also, you should ask customs why they put it in website if you ask me why i bring!! everybody has a reason!

You can buy commercially prepared and packaged spices in your country and bring those, if unopened, but home prepared spices will not be accepted.

Dried dates (with seeds removed) are about NZD6/kg (if you shop around a bit) so possibly not worth bringing,  Indian almonds are a different matter, this product (which seems to be from a different tree to normal almonds) seems to cost more than NZD100/kg,  almonds are on the allowed list, but Indian almonds are not. I do not know what would happen if you tried to import these.

Comment: Thanks. So i cant bring dried indian almond?https://www.google.com/search?q=Indian+almonds&client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&prmd=isnv&sxsrf=AJOqlzVU--XIjJ6kqjaaqnAkyu48uhjivw:1678159405376&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4o-_57sj9AhVLtKQKHTGOD7cQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=360&bih=655&dpr=2#imgrc=XZF5WjxciAeRkM

Comment: @Turan Linking to a search engine is generally not good as it will give people in different places different results. I see 'normal' almonds there, and I also see [Cashew nuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashew#/media/File:CashewSnack.jpg). Both are fairly available. I am not sure about actual 'indian almonds', but there are specialist Indian food shops that likely have them.

Comment: NO. I just want to know you mean from indian almond the one in the photo?

Comment: This is the first time I have encountered Indian almonds (terminalia: catappa),  I don't know enough about them to have a useful opinion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia_catappa

Comment: If you're looking for dried indian almond _leaves_, it appears those are sold in NZ too.

Comment: Look my issue is not found in nz or  not. I know everything is found everywhere